# Getting back the paragraph in cleanThesis?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, cleanthesis

I want to use the [cleanthesis template](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) for my PhD dissertation because I'm not into classicThesis. Unfortunately if I press return in my latex code this does not produce an paragraph as usual but an entire new line. Therefore I can't add a paragraph and I have only block text (Funny though: This is exactly what I wanted when I started writing with latex, but now I am really thankful for the paragraph).

Is there a possibility to write an own command that produces a paragraph or can I invert the function of "return" to a paragraph again?

Comment: You may need to clarify your question. A single return acts the same as as space in LaTeX. Two returns (ie a blank  line) ends the paragraph. This is a low level feature that doesn't depend on the document class. What do you mean by "block text" distinct from "paragraph"

Comment: I just dont want that 2 paragraphs are separated by a new line. I would rather like the new paragraph to be indented.

Comment: Your comment is a _lot_ clearer (and more exact) than your question:-) The choice of paragraph style is one of the major design criterion You can change it as shown by Torbjørn but are you sure you really want this class if you don't like this fundamental design choice. (The spacing for all lists and other structures will have been set assuming this default)

Comment: Well I think its better than using classicthemes and chaning the layout of the table of content and somehow the margin^^. But your right, If there would be any other theme style that comes close to this one and uses the paragraph in the default way I am going to switch.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cleanthesis.sty` defines the `parindent`, that is the length by which the first line of a paragraph is indented, to zero. Remove or comment out line 313 in `cleanthesis.sty`, which reads

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
```

to get the default indentation.

In addition, if you're using the given example as a basis, you have to remove `parskip=full` from the options given to the document class.

Finally, `cleanthesis` uses `\titlespacing` from the `titlesec` package, and that introduces a paragraph indent after `section`s and `subsection`s. If you change these to the starred version, the indentation disappears. Hence, in lines 564 and 586 in `cleanthesis.sty`, change `\titlespacing{...` to `\titlespacing*{...`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did work. But now each paragraph starts indented. Is it possible to avoid that? Such that the starting paragraph of a section is not intended?

Comment: @Adam That took too long to figure out, but see my edited answer.