# Customizing clean thesis

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, templates, cleanthesis

I am using the [cleanthesis template](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/). In this template, there is no paragraph by default.

As explained in [Getting back the paragraph in cleanThesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113966/getting-back-the-paragraph-in-cleanthesis), the paragraph can be re-established by commenting out

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
```

in the style class and

```
parskip=full
```

in

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=A4,                   % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
    twoside=true,               % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,                  % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    %parskip=full,              % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,         % prefix for chapter marks
    11pt,                       % font size
    headings=normal,            % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,         % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,               % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,               % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,        % display table captions above the float env
    draft=false,                % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}%
```

After changing this, the header of each chapter does look very crowded and the chapter title is not anymore on the bottom line. How can I keep the paragraph without destroying the header of each chapter?

If the answer is "Build your own thesis template", then I would like to know how I can reproduce the same header of each chapter in the memoir class.

Before re-establish paragraph:
[image]

After adding paragraph:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without changing anything in `cleanthesis.sty`, add the following lines in your document, just before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{\KOMAoptions{parskip=full}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\H@old@schapter}{\KOMAoptions{parskip=full}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\cleanchapterquote}{\KOMAoptions{parskip=full}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\H@old@schapter}{\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\cleanchapterquote}{\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}\vspace*{\baselineskip}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In cleanthesis.sty replace -2.1em by -1.1em or something that you like

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\usekomafont{chapter}}%
    {\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
        {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
            \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
        {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
            \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
        }%
    }%
    {-2.1em}%   % ------> here
    {\ctformatchapter}%
    [\phantomsection]
```